# Why does pointer subtraction in C yield an integer?

Tags: c, pointers

Why if I subtract from a pointer another pointer (integer pointers) without typecasting the result will be 1 and not 4 bytes (like it is when I typecast to int both pointers). Example :

```
int a , b , *p , *q;
p = &b;
q = p + 1; // q = &a;
printf("%d",q - p); // The result will be one .
printf("%d",(int)q - (int)p); // The result will be 4(bytes). The memory address of b minus The memory address of a.
```

Comment: Your code invokes undefined behavior. For pointer difference use `ptrdiff_t` and the appropriate specifier to `printf`.

Comment: It's normal, when you do pointer = pointer + 1, it adds 1 * sizeof(int *);

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant: I believe you mean `1 * sizeof(int)`, not `int*`.

Comment: Because pointer arithmetic is designed to match array indexing. In other words `array[i]` is equivalent to `*(array + i)`.

Comment: That's a good explanation .  @user3386109

Comment: @ShadowRanger: oops yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why If If I subtract from a pointer another pointer (integer pointers) without typecasting the result will be 1 and not 4 bytes

That's the whole point of the data type that a pointer pointing to. It's probably easier to look at an array context like below. The point is regardless of the underlying data type (here `long` or `double`), you can use pointer arithmetic to navigate the array without caring about how exactly the size of its element is. In other words, **(pointer + 1)** means **point the next element** regardless of the type.

```
long l[] = { 10e4, 10e5, 10e6 };
long *pl = l + 1;    // point to the 2nd element in the "long" array.

double d[] = { 10e7, 10e8, 10e9 };
double *pd = d + 2;    // point to the 3rd element in the "double" array.
```

Also note in your code:

```
int a , b , *p , *q;
p = &b;
q = p + 1; // q = &a;   <--- NO this is wrong.
```

The fact that `a` and `b` are **declared** next to each other does not mean that `a` and `b` are **allocated** next to each other in the memory. So `q` is pointing to the memory address next to that of `b` - but what is in that address is undefined.

Comment: Pointing to an uninitialized area is fine and quite common.  This might precede `*q = 7` to initialize the memory (variable).

Comment: But it's definitely not the address of `a` in this code.

Comment: Perhaps it is not `a`, and I agree it is extremely unwise to expect that it is.

Answer (score 5):

According to the C Standard (6.5.6 Additive operators)

> 9 When two pointers are subtracted, **both shall point to elements of
>   the same array object**, or one past the last element of the array
>   object; the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two
>   array elements....

If the two pointers pointed to elements of the same array then as it is said in the quote from the Standard

> the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two  array
>   elements

That is you would get the number of elements of the array between these two pointers. It is the result of the so-called pointer arithmetic.

If you subtract addresses stored in the pointers as integer values then you will get the number that corresponds to the arithmetic subtract operation.

Comment: So the subtraction between `q` and `p` return the ' distance' between 'q' and 'p' . If `p` points to the first  element of array and `q` points to last one . `q - p ` return the number of elements of the array ?

Comment: @Călin Calin, you don't index an `int` array as `array[0]... array[4]... array[8]...` to take account of the data size do you? Its the same way with the pointer arithmetic.

Comment: You overlooked "or one past the last element" immediately after your bolded text.  `q - p` is valid. (But the wrong format specifier was used).

Comment: @CălinCalin If the frist pointer points to the first element and the second pointer points to the one past the last element then their difference gives the number of elements in the array. On the other hand if you will cast th both pointers to type char * then the difference will give the size of the array in bytes because sizeof( char ) is always equal to q. That is if you are considering the array as a characater array then the number of elements of the array is equal to the size of the array in bytes.

Comment: @CălinCalin The same you can get with expression ( q - p ) * sizeof( int ).

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I understood . Thanks , my friend !

Answer (score 3):

Because the `ptrdiff_t` from pointer subtraction is calculated relative to the size of the elements pointed to. It's a lot more convenient that way; for one, it tells you how many times you can increment one pointer before you reach the other pointer.

Answer (score 3):

where you have

```
int a , b , *p , *q;
```

The compiler can put `a` and `b` anywhere. They don't have to even be near each other. Also, when you subtract two `int` pointers, the result is sized in terms of `int`, not bytes.

Answer (score 2):

C is not assembly language.  So pointers are not just plain integers -- pointers are special guys that know how to point to other things.

It's fundamental to the way pointers and pointer arithmetic work in C that they can point to successive elements of an array.  So if we write

```
int a[10];
int *p1 = &a[4];
int *p2 = &a[3];
```

then `p1 - p2` will be 1.  The result is 1 because the "distance" between `a[3]` and `a[4]` is one int.  The result is 1 because 4 - 3 = 1.  The result is *not* 4 (as you might have thought it would be if you know that `int`s are 32 bits on your machine) because we're not interesting in doing assembly language programming or working with machine addresses; we're doing higher-level language programming with an array, and we're thinking in those terms.

(But, yes, at the machine address level, the way `p2 - p1` is computed is typically as (<raw address value in `p2`> - <raw address value in `p1`>) / `sizeof(int)`.)